# Swift set value to enum in my custom class

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I'm wondering how can I set a value to my enum that is declared in my **Alert.swift** custom class in order to the button change the style.
Here is my code so far:

```
var alert: Alert!
```

in my viewDidLoad I create the alert

```
alert = Alert(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width , height: 60), buttonType: .Uno, disabled: true)
```

and I have a custom class Alert.swift where I have declared the enum:

```
enum ButtonType {
    case Cero
    case Uno
    case Dos
    case Tres
}
```

and then in the initializer:

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect, buttonType: ButtonType, disabled: Bool = false) {
    self.init(frame: frame)

    switch buttonType {
    case .Uno:
        rightButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.alertView.frame.width-60, 0, 60, 60)
        rightButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        rightButton.addTarget(self, action: nil, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "rightButtonImage"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        rightButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
        alertView.addSubview(rightButton)
        ...
```

My question is, once the alert is created with

```
alert = Alert(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width , height: 60), buttonType: .Uno, disabled: true)
```

if I want to change the button style, let's say doing something like that:

```
alert.buttonType = .Dos
```

I don't know how to manage that in my **Alert.swift** class, I only know how to set the style while I'm setting that value while creating the alert.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add something like this to your `Alert` class:

```
class Alert {

    var buttonType: ButtonType {
        didSet {
            configureForButtonType()
        }
    }


    private func configureForButtonType() {

        switch buttonType {
        case .Uno:
            ...
            break

        case .Cero:
            ...
            break

        case .Dos:
            ...
            break

        case .Tres:
            ...
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Put all of your styling from the `switch` on `buttonType` in the `configureForButtonType()` method. When `buttonType` is set at initialization, the class will configure itself.

Comment: Thanks @Adam H. I did what you say but I'm getting the following error: `Property 'self.buttonType' not initialized at super.init call`

Comment: in     `override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        setup()
    }`

Comment: You must either set `buttonType` before the `super.init()` call or change `var buttonType: ButtonType` to `var buttonType: ButtonType!`

Answer (score 2):

With Swift this is actually quite a easy problem to solve. So what you need is firstly some state. You need to know what your current button setting is. I would recommend a class property for this, such as:

```
var buttonState = ButtonType.Uno
```

Okay. Now that's done, you can simply check for changes within this property. There are several things you could do here but the simplest would be to use the didSet facility.

```
var buttonState = ButtonType.Uno {
   didSet {
      switch buttonState {
         case .Uno:
            ...
      }
   }
}
```

Ideally you don't want your entire switch in here, but you could easily move it into a function and reference it from here.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to the Alert class:

```
var buttonType {
    didSet {
        print("Add update here or call func")
    }
}
```

And in your init code set this property:

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect, buttonType: ButtonType, disabled: Bool = false) {
    self.buttonType = buttonType    
    self.init(frame: frame)
    ...
}
```

Now the property can be changed outside of the init and the class can make additional changes as needed.